Making Tesseract read text from an image with enclosing box around the text
With the default available trained model for tesseract, it fails to recognize the text within box below. Is there any way to tweak the API parameters to read the below text, rather than going with training the model with additional images?


Why did you not read tesseract documentation? tesseract 51Y9CTgH.png - something_from_doc:  AQUAGOAT

Is that a command line usage? I'm doing with Java and it returned some junk text for the labels.

Yes. If you have problem with tesseract you always need to test image with  tesseract executable to eliminate problem with tesseract (java) wrapper.

Actually I don't think it is a problem specific to the java wrapper. I didn't provide all the information before. The image I provided is what I clipped out manually from a larger image. When I run tesseract on the parent image is when I have the problem, that the text inside the green box doesn't get read.
